# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to output a player's stats in a table. Not all players will have stats depending on the day. I have tried other ways and all are still complaining. Here is the code I have now:

```
      <tbody>
            @foreach(var player in @ViewBag.Roster){
                int index = 0;
                <tr>
                    <td>@player.Name, @player.TeamName @player.Position</td>
                    if(@ViewBag.Stats[index] == null){
                        <td>--</td>
                        <td>--</td>
                        <td>--</td>
                        <td>--</td>
                    }
                    else{
                        <td>@ViewBag.Stats[index].Points</td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.Stats[index].Rebounds</td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.Stats[index].Assists</td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.Stats[index].Turnovers</td>                        
                    }
                </tr>
                index++;
            }

        </tbody>
```

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Source Error:

Line 32:                         }

Line 33:                         else{

Line 34:                         @ViewBag.Stats[index].Points

Line 35:                         @ViewBag.Stats[index].Rebounds

Line 36:                         @ViewBag.Stats[index].Assists

Comment: Can't understand what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am trying to check if each player has a stat. If they do I will output it. Else just output '--'. Maybe there is a different syntax for checking if a stat exists?

Comment: Yes! That worked, but now my index++ is not working. Any ideas where I should put it? It just output the same stats for all my players.

Comment: Well I don't know if it solved my original problem of outputting the '--' if the stat is null. But the page loaded with no errors

Comment: I have posted an answer for the problem with index..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK I am posting the full answer here -

1. Try `@` before `if(@ViewBag.Stats[index] == null){` and remove `@` from `@ViewBag` inside the `if` so that it look like this - `@if(ViewBag.Stats[index] == null){`
2. You are setting `index = 0`, inside `foreach`, so it is initialised in every loop.  Initialise it outside `foreach` like this

   `var index = 0;
   foreach ...`

if you are facing problem for the scope try this -

```
@{
    var index = 0;
    foreach (....) {
        .......
        index++
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this made me check my *.cshtml again and I found a reference to a model that does not exist after I made a copy/paste from another code (using Razor syntax), something like '@Model.item'  at the end of my code. Just commenting that line of code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep track of the index, why dont you rewrite your loop as:

```
    var obj = new string[] { "", "", "" };

    for(var index = 0; index < obj.Length; index++)
    {
        var item = obj[index];

        /* DO STUFF WITH ITEM */
    }

    foreach(var item in obj.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }))
    {
        /* DO STUFF WITH item.Value */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both cases suggested above, but with no luck.
Then finally I had to initialize my ViewBag collection in the Controller's Index method itself.
So when I did something like this,

```
var stringArray = new string[10] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
ViewBag.doc = stringArray;
```

it worked. (I had 10 elements. If they were more, had to do something else for initialization.)
My code on the view part is as follows now:

```
  @for (var itm =0; itm< 10; itm++)
                        {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Documents[itm].doc"></label>
                        <input type="file" asp-for="Documents[itm].doc" />
                        @if (ViewBag.doc[itm] != "")
                        {<a asp-area="" asp-page="/wwwroot/CaseDocuments/@ViewBag.doc[itm]">@ViewBag.doc[itm]</a>
                            <label asp-for="Documents[itm].remove"></label>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a.Documents[itm].remove)
                        }
                    </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Documents[itm].desc"></label>
                                <textarea asp-for="Documents[itm].desc" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        }
```